# Guice: Given Class<T>, how to get a Key for List<T>?

Tags: generics, guice, typeliteral

Guice TypeLiterals allow you to represent a generic type with specific type arguments, like `List<String>`, and use that in binding expressions. Suppose that instead of knowing the type argument for the list at compile time, you have a Class object for the type at runtime (in this case, String.class). Is there a way to bind a list of this type?

For example, consider the following method:

```
public void bindListOfClass(Class<?> clazz, List<?> list) {
    bind(????).to(list);
}
```

What, if anything, can be used in that bind call such that `bindListOfClass(String.class, list)` is equivalent to `bind(new TypeLiteral<List<String>>(){}).to(list)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following helper method:

```
import com.google.inject.util.Types;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> TypeLiteral<List<T>> listOf(Class<T> type) {
    return (TypeLiteral<List<T>>)TypeLiteral.get(Types.listOf(type));
}
```

More here: https://github.com/tavianator/sangria/blob/master/sangria-core/src/main/java/com/tavianator/sangria/core/TypeLiterals.java